# Jenkins JobDSL multibranchPipelineJob change script path

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-job-dsl, multibranch-pipeline

I am trying to create a multibranchPipelineJob in jobDSL, however the Jenkinsfile is at an alternative location to the default. 
I have looked through the docs https://jenkinsci.github.io/job-dsl-plugin/#path/multibranchPipelineJob
and I cannot see a way to do this.
Looking at the config.xml for a manually created multibranchPipelineJob the scriptPath is in the  section, but I cannot find a DSL method to set this.

Can anyone offer any help on how to do this?
Cheers

Comment: Hmmm it appears that the ability to do this is in master 
https://github.com/jenkinsci/job-dsl-plugin/blob/master/job-dsl-core/src/main/groovy/javaposse/jobdsl/dsl/jobs/MultibranchWorkflowJob.groovy
So i might just have to wait for 1.67 of DSL to come out :(

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Job DSL now exposes a way to do this:

```
multibranchPipelineJob('my-build') {
    factory {
        workflowBranchProjectFactory {
            scriptPath('path-to-Jenkinsfile')
        }
    }
}
```

Confirmed working with Job DSL 1.69, and is available since 1.67 according to the release notes.

**Edit:** Tested again with Job DSL 1.77 and it's still working as expected. If you want to see the documentation for this syntax you'll have to look at a Jenkins installation that has the Multibranch Pipeline plugin installed, at this path:

https://your-jenkins-url/plugin/job-dsl/api-viewer/index.html#path/multibranchPipelineJob-factory-workflowBranchProjectFactory-scriptPath

Comment: This should be definitly added to the Jenkins Job Dsl documentation.

Comment: Can multiple scriptPath be added?

Comment: Strange could neither get it running on 1.77 / or the DSL playground. I get the following error: javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.DslScriptException: (script, line 3) No signature of method: javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.helpers.workflow.BranchProjectFactoryContext.workflowBranchProjectFactory() is applicable for argument types: (script$_run_closure1$_closure2$_closure3) values: [script$_run_closure1$_closure2$_closure3@33e4c96c]

Comment: doesn't seem to work on https://job-dsl.herokuapp.com/ it throws javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.DslScriptException: (script, line 3) No signature of method: javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.helpers.workflow.BranchProjectFactoryContext.workflowBranchProjectFactory() is applicable for argument types: (script$_run_closure1$_closure2$_closure3) values: [script$_run_closure1$_closure2$_closure3@ef99655]

Answer (score 8):

As this question still proves popular, to do this in JCasC you can do this

```
jobs:
  - script: >
      folder('common');
      multibranchPipelineJob('common/jcasc-deploy') {
        factory {
          workflowBranchProjectFactory {
            scriptPath('Jenkinsfile')
          }
        }
        branchSources {
          branchSource {
            source {
              gitSCMSource {
                remote('git@gitlab.com:PROJECT/REPO.git')
                credentialsId('gitlab-key')
                id('jcasc-deploy')
              }
            }
          buildStrategies {
            buildAllBranches {
              strategies {
                skipInitialBuildOnFirstBranchIndexing()
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
      triggers {
        periodicFolderTrigger {
          interval('1440')
        }
      }
      configure { node ->
        node / sources / data / 'jenkins.branch.BranchSource' / source / traits {
          'jenkins.plugins.git.traits.BranchDiscoveryTrait'()
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: This is useful but it didn't work for me initially until I realized that this requires the `basic-branch-build-strategies` plugin for the `buildStrategies` part to work.

Comment: @Yeroc thanks, your comment saved a lot working time

Answer (score 7):

After a fair amount of googling, I found something that works:

```
configure {
    it / factory(class: 'org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.multibranch.WorkflowBranchProjectFactory') {
        owner(class: 'org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.multibranch.WorkflowMultiBranchProject', reference: '../..')
        scriptPath("jenkins/[where ever you want]/Jenkinsfile")
    }
}
```

This seems to work for me.

Comment: This is the solution for everybody where the accepted answer does not work, which currently seems to be the case for jobDSL 1.77.

Comment: @JoergS This answer should work for any version of Job DSL, but it's using a more "raw" syntax from before Job DSL supported the nicer syntax. Job DSL 1.67 introduced a nicer syntax which still works on 1.77 (I tested on a fresh Jenkins install with Job DSL 1.77 to be sure).

Answer (score 3):

The setting is a bit hidden, but the [Automatically Generated DSL](https://github.com/jenkinsci/job-dsl-plugin/wiki/Automatically-Generated-DSL) supports setting the script path for a multibranch job:

```
multibranchPipelineJob('example') {
  factory {
    workflowMultiBranchProjectFactory {
      scriptPath('my-location/Jenkinsfile')
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Although I can understand why it _should_ work, it didn't for me :-(. Have you tested it @daspilker ?

Answer (score 0):

We found this approach to work on the [dsl playground](https://job-dsl.herokuapp.com/) and when using a gradle JavaExec task in addition to the plugin.  Found it [here](https://gist.github.com/jondkelley/fc7812158d98003ea504365a6195d59a).

```
    configure {

        it / factory(class: 'org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.multibranch.WorkflowBranchProjectFactory') {
            owner(class: 'org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.multibranch.WorkflowMultiBranchProject', reference: '../..')
            scriptPath("jenkinsfile")
        }
    }
```

Our Gradle Approach is as follows which lets engineers generate locally and we have jenkins generate/store with the build.  This makes diffing against current easier.

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        groovy {
            srcDirs = ['src']
        }
        resources {
            srcDirs = ['resources']
        }
    }
    test {
        groovy {
            srcDirs = ['test']
        }
        resources {
            srcDirs = ['resources']
        }
    }
    jobs {
        groovy {
            srcDirs 'jenkins-job-dsl'
            compileClasspath += main.compileClasspath
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
...
compile 'org.jenkins-ci.plugins:job-dsl-core:1.77'
}
...
/**
 * get current branch
 * @return uses vairable on jenkins and runs git command locally
 */
String getBranchName() {
    if (System.env.BRANCH_NAME) {
        // Jenkins
        if (System.env.BRANCH_NAME == 'master') {
            return ''
        } else {
            return '_' + System.env.BRANCH_NAME.toLowerCase().replaceAll("/", "_")
        }
    } else {
        return '_localDev'
    }
}
```